# cocos2d-x sqlite database is empty

Tags: android, sqlite, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d iPhone development to use sqlite database first I copy it from resource to DocumentsDirectory and then open it.

```
BOOL success;

DBName = @"StageDB.sqlite";
documentsPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
documentDir = [documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];
DBPath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:DBName];

//check if present
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
success=[fm fileExistsAtPath:DBPath];

if(success)
{
    NSLog(@"Already present");
}
else
{
    //Copy from bundle to DocumentsDirectory on first run. Where DB won't be available in DocumentsDirectory.
    NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"StageDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSError*error;
    success=[fm copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:DBPath error:&error];

    if(success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Created successfully");
    }
}

sqlite3_open([DBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK
```

In cocos2d-x Android development I use this without copy and the database is empty.

```
pDB = NULL; //for database path
char* errMsg = NULL; //for error message
std::string sqlstr; //for sql query string
int result;
std::string dbPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getWritablePath();
dbPath.append("StageDB.sqlite");
result = sqlite3_open(dbPath.c_str(),&pDB);
if (result != SQLITE_OK)
    CCLOG("OPENING WRONG, %d, MSG:%s",result,errMsg);
else
    CCLOG("result %d",result);
```

This select returns zero:

```
std::string sqlstr = "select count (type) AS cou from sqlite_master where type = 'table'";
```

In cocos2d-x I must copy database to use it?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS use `<ApplicationHome>/Documents` as storage path for Purchases and Savegames.
You can use `<ApplicationHome>/Library/Caches` for temporary data that may get deleted any time.
In Cocos2d-x v3.0 and v 2.2, `getWritablePath()` returns: `<ApplicationHome>/Documents/`

For Android you would use the value returned by `Context.getFilesDir()` and place your SQLite database here. This usually return something like: `/data/data/<Package Name>/`

`std::cout` your `dbPath` to see what it thinks is your path.

`string sqlstr = "select count (type) AS cou from sqlite_master where type = 'table'";` should return the number of tables in your database.